# How to debug JupyterLab server extension

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have created a [JupyterLab extension](https://github.com/jld23/sas_kernel_ext/tree/main/sas2nb)
that converts a SAS file (`*.sas`) to a Jupyter notebook (`*.ipynb`).

The extension works fine on my development systems (ubuntu and osx) but when I try and use it inside of [binder](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jld23/sas_kernel/HEAD) I get 404 errors.

Here is the browser console when working:
[image]

Here is the browser console inside of binder (not working):
[image]

Obviously there is something different between the two environments but I can't figure out what it is.

The extensions appear to be installed correctly in binder, so I'm not sure what to do next.

```
jadean@6541034d7640:~$ jupyter server extension list
Config dir: /home/jadean/.jupyter

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_server/transutils.py:13: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
  warnings.warn(warn_msg, FutureWarning)
Config dir: /srv/conda/envs/notebook/etc/jupyter
    jupyterlab enabled
    - Validating jupyterlab...
      jupyterlab 3.0.12 OK
    nbclassic enabled
    - Validating nbclassic...
      nbclassic  OK
    sas2nb enabled
    - Validating sas2nb...
      sas2nb 0.1.0 OK

Config dir: /usr/local/etc/jupyter

jadean@6541034d7640:~$ jupyter labextension list
/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyter_server/transutils.py:13: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
  warnings.warn(warn_msg, FutureWarning)
JupyterLab v3.0.12
/srv/conda/envs/notebook/share/jupyter/labextensions
        jlab-create-sas-file v0.1.0 enabled OK (python, jlab_create_sas_file)
        sas2nb v0.1.0 enabled OK
        @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
```

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like your extension is trying to contact localhost (127.0.0.1) on Binder, but it should instead send the request to binder server that is currently running. I think that you may have incorrect baseURL set in your front-end extension

Comment: @krassowski, I used `repo2docker` for the screen shot above so it was running locally but the behavior is the same as a public hosted image. 
I used the cookiecutter and didn't modify the `setup_handlers` [method](https://github.com/jld23/sas_kernel_ext/blob/main/sas2nb/sas2nb/handlers.py#L42)

Comment: Do you have a binder link for me to take a look? Also, it might help you to get an answer faster if you post a link to this question on https://gitter.im/jupyterlab/jupyterlab too.

Comment: @krassowski, thanks for the suggestion I'll ask on gitter. The binder location is a link in the orginal post. Here it is again for expediency https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jld23/sas_kernel/HEAD

Comment: This link opens a jupyter notebook, not jupyter lab though.